# Python class define not being recognized

Tags: python

Ok, so I've been trying to create a Python 3.9 program that's designed to ask the user for the sales amount for the month, and call the "county" and "state" functions, to find the taxes collected on it. I've been reading up on functions, classes, and whatnot but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. It's supposed to have the program tell the total sales tax collected at the end of the program. (So if 100000 was entered by the user, the total tax collected would be 7750 for that month.) But everything I do leads to a brick wall, as of now I'm getting: "name 'main' is not defined"

This feels like one of those issues that takes like 3 seconds to fix but I just can't seem to pinpoint the issue. None of the online tutorials or other questions have really helped me either. Any thoughts?

```
class Tax:

    #combined sales
    def sales_combined():

        county_sales_number() + state_sales_number()
 
    #main
    def main():

        sales_Amount = int(input("What was the sale amount for the month? "))

        print("The total sales tax collected is " + sales_combined())


    #county sales division
    def county_tax():

        countyValue = 0.015

    #state sales division
    def state_tax():

        stateValue = 0.0625


    #county sales
    def county_sales_number():

        sales_Amount / county_tax()



    #state sales
    def state_sales_number():

        sales_Amount / state_tax()

main()
```

Comment: I recommend you read up about the difference between methods and functions. The short answer is, `main` is an (instance) method of the `Tax` class. You need to instantiate `Tax` first in order to call `main`.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects. tl;dr: you need `self` and call it like `t = Tax(); t.main()`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well that was certainly helpful

Comment: @mapf Thank you

Comment: @c2huc2hu I will do that, thank you

Comment: You really need to read a basic tutorial on Python class definitions. I think the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you came from a Java background. In your snippet, `main` is a function inside of `Tax`, so if you want to access it, you need to do

```
class Tax:
    ...

Tax.main()
```

However, this will raise an AttributeError, since `sales_combined` is not defined. To be able to access it, you need to make `main` an *instance* method of `Tax`:

```
class Tax:
    ...

    def main(self):
        ...
        # Access the method using `self`
        self.sales_combined()

tax = Tax()
tax.main()
```

An alternative (and recommended) approach is to make it a function, so you would separate your business logic from your driver code:

```
def main():
    tax = Tax()
    sales_Amount = int(input("What was the sale amount for the month? "))
    print("The total sales tax collected is " + tax.sales_combined())

class Tax:
    ...

main()
```

Comment: `Tax().main` is a bound method. `Tax.main` is just a function. (Python3 doesn't really have unbound methods anymore, since there is no significant difference between an unbound method and the function from which it was derived.)